# How to determine if sphere is in front of plane

Tags: math, geometry, directx

I want to do frustum culling for my engine :)

On [this site](http://www.chadvernon.com/blog/resources/directx9/frustum-culling/) seems to be nice example how to do this, but there is one thing I don't get:

```
if ( D3DXPlaneDotCoord( &m_frustum[i], pPosition ) + radius < 0 )
        {
            // Outside the frustum, reject it!
            return FALSE;
        }
```

Is why there is a radius for?
Or maybe what is dependence between dot product and distance from plane?

Cause with my actual knowledge I would calculate it like that:
calculate dot product of plane. And as vectors are normalized dot product is equal to cosinus of angle between vectors. So it can return values between -1 and 1.(Thats why I dont understand why radius is added). And if cos > 0 means that angle is between 0 and 90 degrees. So center point is in front of plane. Then I would use equation for distance of point from plane. And check if that distance is higer than radius of sphere. But this guy have this in that one equation. What magic is behid that?

Ok I see where is my mistake dot procuct is not equal to cos of angle, but cos of angle and length of vector P( describing position of center of sphere). So what exactly is `cos*|P| = ?`
http://tinypic.com/r/2vxrpkw/5( no rep for images )
Probably answered own question brb( wikipedia ) :)

Yeah exactly. My P is not P desribing point in coordinate system, but It's P - known point of plane. So it's vector between point and know point of plane. Everything seems legit. Thanks for help :P It's nicely explained here: www.songho.ca/math/plane/plane.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be seen as a projection of the pPosition along the plane's normal.

If the *length* of this projection plus the plane's D component minus the sphere radius is less than zero means the sphere is behind.